# Is there a way to pick up seek "event" in Android Music Player?

Tags: java, android, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm developing an application which works with information broadcasted by the default Android music player.

I have set up an IntentFilter and BroadcastReceiver in order to listen for metadatachanged or playstatechanged events of the Android music player:

```
IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
```

Thus I'm able to pick up when the user changes a song or pauses/starts playing a song. However, I'm interested to know when the user seeks forward or backward through a song - I need to know how many seconds are skipped.

I don't think there's an intent action for seeking? Any ideas as to how I should go about detecting this?

Comment: There is no single "the default Android music player". There are thousands of Android device models. These ship with hundreds of different pre-installed music players, to go along with the thousands of music players that users can install from the Play Store or elsewhere. None have to have an API for third-party apps to monitor playback.

Comment: Take w/ a grain of salt for I haven't touched MP in a while, but back in ICS/JellyBean it was "not possible" to obtain the instance of the current media player (unless you hacked through the `ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo` to find the MP and bind it to your service; this would have allowed you to set a listener for a seek state change. I don't think you will be able to do this, but keep exploring and share your results ;)